# No able to update julia inside it or using git

Tags: julia

Innocent question, I have on my julia session:

```
Version 0.3.0-prerelease+1641 (2014-02-19 18:31 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit 7812ecd* (43 days old master)
|__/                   |  x86_64-suse-linux
```

Which says it has 43 days old master. How can I update my julia installation? I went through the docs and couldn't find what to do except for ubuntu, which I don't need it since I use archlinux. Pkg doesn't do what I want since this is for installed packages, not to update my julia version.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to install up-to-date Julia: [snapshots builds](http://julialang.org/downloads/#Prerelease.snapshot) and [building from source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#source-download-and-compilation)

(How did you install Julia in the first place?)

Comment: I cloned the repo from github

Comment: this causes a conflict that I have already seen in machines using macOS (I use ubuntu). For some reason, when one do this, the symbolic link is modified and points to some library, if I remember correctly, julialibreadline.so or something like that. Erasing the link and typing make will yield a segmentation fault, so I'm compiling again the whole julia program, sadly.